# WPF TabItem OnMouseOver shall trigger the visibility of a Button inside the TabItem

Tags: wpf, triggers, datatemplate

I have a TabControl containing TabItems. I overwrote their ItemTemplate to contain:

- A TextBlock showing the caption of the TabItem
- A Button (X) which closes the tab

Now I would like to make the "X"-Button only visible, when the TabItem is either selected or the mouse is over it.

This is my XAML code so far...

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding OpenedItems}">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Name="grid" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabCaption}"  
                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                   Foreground="White"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                   Margin="3" 
                                   Name="label_TabTitle" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <Button Content="X"  
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Foreground="White"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                Margin="3" 
                                Name="button_close" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                Width="20" 
                                Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" 
                                Visibility="Hidden" 
                                Click="button_close_Click_1">
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>

                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" >
                            <Setter TargetName="button_close" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1C1C1C" />
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding TabContentView}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                                <Grid Name="Grid"
                              Background="{StaticResource GrayBrush}">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                  ContentSource="Header"
                                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True">
                                    </ContentPresenter>
                                </Grid>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Grid" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BlueBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Grid" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LightBlueBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TabControl>
```

With the Trigger inside the DataTemplate it kind of works.. but: you have to hover the mouse directly over the Label in order to show the button. So basically, it is impossible to click the button, because it disappears again.

I would appreciate any help with these WPF Templates!

Thanks, Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though your TabItem does not have the background set so it is not catching the `MouseOverEvent`. Since the TextBlock has the foreground set and has text, it captures the MouseOverEvent. Try setting the `Background` child grid of the `DataTemplate` to `Transparent` and you should see that the `MouseOverEvent` will be caught and show the close button.

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding OpenedItems}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <Grid Name="grid" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
                ...
             </Grid>
             ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    ...
 </TabControl>
```

Comment: Works like a charm!! Thank you, I would have never realized this is the problem...

Answer (score 1):

If you set opacity instead of visibility it works. Removed all references to Visibility, changed to Opacity:

You may want to check my code edit. Not 100% sure it's a duplicate of what you had, but the idea works. Why? Not sure. :) I'm guessing the Hidden-Button was swallowing the MouseEnter events, but refusing to pass them on because it was hidden.

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding OpenedItems}">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Name="grid" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabCaption}"  
                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                   Foreground="White"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                   Margin="3" 
                                   Name="label_TabTitle" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <Button Content="X"  
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Foreground="White"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                Margin="3" 
                                Name="button_close" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                Width="20" 
                                Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" 
                                Opacity="0"
                                Click="button_close_Click_1">
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>

                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" >
                            <Setter TargetName="button_close" Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1C1C1C" />
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding TabContentView}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                                <Grid Name="Grid"
                              Background="{StaticResource GrayBrush}">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                  ContentSource="Header"
                                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True">
                                    </ContentPresenter>
                                </Grid>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Grid" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BlueBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Grid" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LightBlueBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TabControl>
```